# Landscape not working for overlay Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

Basically, my app is AppLocker.
When you click the locked app it shows overlay Lock.
All was working until I notice that LockOverlay not looking good when shown on Landscape apps like Games.

What I did until now.
---> I created a landscape layout for lock Overlay, but the problem still exist, the landscape layout is not applied on Overlay.

Portrait
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlUQp.png)

Landscape
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uidlt.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you please share the XML?